# Nunit testing exceptions - how to test `ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName, message)`

Tags: c#, nunit

There are quite a few threads about Nunit and testing exceptions. However, I was not able to figure out how to apply this on my specific code. The parameter are causing me some trouble.

The exception I am throwing looks like this:
`throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName: nameof(valueMayNotBeZero), message: "The argument must have a positive value!");`

Mentoring and comments are much appreciated.

#### My Question

- What other ways are there to test the exception?
- What best practices have you from your experience?

In this example I am creating an exception object and checking the property `Message` against my actual string. This seems to be a bit awkward. But this is the only way I got my test running.
`var result = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => testObject.ThrowAnException(valueMayNotBeZero));`

`Assert.That(result.Message, Is.EqualTo("The argument must have a positive value! (Parameter 'valueMayNotBeZero')"));`

#### The Code

`Program.cs`

```
using StackOverflow;

GenerateException demo = new();
try
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Value: {demo.ThrowAnException(1.5):f2}");

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unexpected Exception!");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

Console.WriteLine($"\n***** Press ENTER To Continue *****");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`GenerateException.cs`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public class GenerateException
{
    public double ThrowAnException(double valueMayNotBeZero)
    {
        if (valueMayNotBeZero <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(valueMayNotBeZero), "The argument must have a positive value!");
        }

        return valueMayNotBeZero;
    }
}
```

#### The Test

`GenerateExceptionTests.cs`

```
using StackOverflow;

namespace SackOverflowTest;

public class GenerateExceptionTests
{
    private static IEnumerable<double> SourceProvider()
    {
        yield return 10.0;
        yield return 99.99;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<double> SourceProviderException()
    {
        // GrossSalary
        yield return 0.0;
        yield return -10.0;
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(SourceProvider))]
    public void CreateNoExceptionTest(double valueMayNotBeZero)
    {
        // ***** Arrange *****
        GenerateException testObject = new();

        // ***** Act *****
        var result = testObject.ThrowAnException(valueMayNotBeZero);

        // ***** Assert *****
        Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(valueMayNotBeZero));
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(SourceProviderException))]
    public void CreateAnExceptionTest(double valueMayNotBeZero)
    {
        // ***** Arrange *****
        GenerateException testObject = new();

        // ***** Act *****
        var result = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => testObject.ThrowAnException(valueMayNotBeZero));

        // ***** Assert *****
        Assert.That(result.Message, Is.EqualTo("The argument must have a positive value! (Parameter 'valueMayNotBeZero')"));
        // somehow not working; logic error?
        //Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => BusinessMiniJob.CalculateEmployeeSalary(valueMayNotBeZero), "The argument must have a positive value!");
        //Assert.That(() => Throws.TypeOf<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>().And.Property(nameof(valueMayNotBeZero)).And.Message.Equals("The argument must have a positive value!"));
    }
}
```

#### Code in my current project

Why do I need to test the exception?
In my current project, I have methods receiving a `double` as parameter. If this value is `<= 0` then the exception is thrown. And since I am at the beginning to work with unit tests, I thought this situation must be tested, too.

```
    public static double CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(double grossSalary)
    {
        if (grossSalary <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(grossSalary), "The argument must have a positive value!");
        }

        return grossSalary * RentenversichungArbeitgeberPflichtanteil;
    }
```

Comment: What are you testing here? In the code shown, you seem to be testing that the .NET ArgumentOutOfRangeException works correctly, but that's code that belongs to somebody else. What do you need to test about this in the system you are testing?

Comment: @Charlie - I have edited my thread; and the end of it you will see one method of my current project; in short: to prevent the code from performing incorrect calcuatlions, I have to make sure the argument is positive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i try to response at the last part of your question, taking into account your last example. First of all, you have to test your logic not the .NET `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.
For do this you should create three different scenario for testing all cases in which the value of `grossSalary` can be found, like that:

```
    public class PensionContributionTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution_NegativeValue_ThrowsException()
        {
            // Arrange
            double negativeGrossSalary = -1000.0; // Adjust the value as needed

            // Act & Assert
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() =>
            {
                CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(negativeGrossSalary);
            }, "The argument must have a positive value!");
        }

        [Test]
        public void CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution_ZeroValue_ThrowsException()
        {
            // Arrange
            double zeroGrossSalary = 0.0; // Adjust the value as needed

            // Act & Assert
            Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() =>
            {
                CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(zeroGrossSalary);
            }, "The argument must have a positive value!");
        }

        [Test]
        public void CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution_PositiveValue_DoesNotThrowException()
        {
            // Arrange
            double positiveGrossSalary = 5000.0; // Adjust the value as needed

            // Act & Assert
            Assert.DoesNotThrow(() =>
            {
                var result = CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(positiveGrossSalary);
                // You can also add assertions to check the result if needed
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for your replies!

#### My Learning

I need a lot of training using these lamda expressions.

#### The Solution

One of my attempts did look like this. And it doesn't work due to the incorrect use of the syntax.

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => 
    BusinessMiniJob.CalculateEmployeeSalary(valueMayNotBeZero), 
    "The argument must have a positive value!");
```

Luca`s code does look like this (modified to my current test). This code works fine. And to me it is a better and more readable solution, than I have figured out (see top of the thread).

```
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() =>
        {
            BusinessMiniJob.CalculateEmployeeSalary(grossSalary);
        }, "The argument must have a positive value!");
```

#### Updated Project Code

Here I am testing the exceptions.

```
    private static IEnumerable<double> SourceProviderException()
    {
        // GrossSalary
        yield return 0.0;
        yield return -10.0;
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(SourceProviderException))]
    public void EmployerStatutoryPensionContributionTest_ThrowsException(double grossSalary)
    {
        // ***** Arrange *****

        // ***** Act & Assert *****
        Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() =>
        {
            BusinessMiniJob.CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(grossSalary);
        }, "The argument must have a positive value!");
    }
```

Here I am testing the calculation of the method. Providing the `grossSalary` and listing the expected results. (in this scenario there are some parameter I don't use; there are more methods using the same `SourceProvider`).

```
    private static IEnumerable<double[]> SourceProvider()
    {
        // GrossSalary, Salary, EmployeeStatutoryPensionContribution, EmployerStatutoryPensionContribution
        yield return new[] { 175.00, 168.70, 6.30, 26.25 };
        yield return new[] { 150.00, 139.95, 10.05, 22.50 };
        yield return new[] { 25.00, -3.80, 28.80, 3.75 };
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(SourceProvider))]
    public void EmployerStatutoryPensionContributionTest(double grossSalary, double salary, double employeeContribution, double employerContribution)
    {
        // ***** Arrange *****

        // ***** Act *****
        var result = BusinessMiniJob.CalculateEmployerStatutoryPensionContribution(grossSalary);

        // ***** Assert *****
        Assert.That(result.ToString("c2"), Is.EqualTo(employerContribution.ToString("c2")));
    }
```